# Why in the world do we have [stack-exchange]?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

Apparently, we have a [stack-exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) tag, with a long wiki description describing the network of sites.

Why?

Well, now we've got a baker's dozen questions that are either:

- a support question that should be asked here on our Meta or on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com)
- a general web app question that only tangentially relates to Stack Exchange

Many are too old to be migrated, but the tag shouldn't exist. Let's clean it up.

Comment: We also have [meta-tag:stackexchange]. Should we add this tag as a tag to this question?

Answer (score 3):

A few years back a portion of the Webapps community said that Stack Exchange is a web application and as such should be treated as one in the context of this site, not be given special treatment.

Robert Cartaino from SE Staff stated that these questions should be moved to meta.stackoverflow.com (this was before meta.stackexchange.com introduction)

Honestly, I'm indifferent and as such will only move questions that directly need support from SE Staff such as bug reports. To get a more concrete decision you will have to ask the other mods or escalate to meta.stackexchange.com

<sub>Rose is a rose is a rose is a rose.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The only Qs at present tagged [stack-exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stack-exchange) are Closed (4 in number). It seems conceivable that there may be a requirement for the tag in the future but I think not at the moment.

As a courtesy to our users who are also users of other SE sites we should aim to be consistent with other sites in the family, where practical. Although for WA SE might be considered just another Web Application for all others it is meta where the workings and policies of the main site/s are discussed so where there is a mixture of both aspects (just another web app/workings & policies) we should handle the Q through meta.

The attendance is very much lower on meta but those few who are involved are probably very much better qualified than our average user to address such a question and quality should at least offset quantity.